# Testing if 'isChecked' prop has changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am struggling with testing if class's prop value is chaning after on clicking switcher.

So here I have component class (nothing complicated -.-):

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'sps-flow-asset-switcher',
templateUrl: './flow-asset-switcher.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./flow-asset-switcher.component.scss'],
})

export class FlowAssetSwitcherComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() isChecked: boolean;
@Output() checkedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}

onChange(e): void {
    this.isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.checkedChange.emit(this.isChecked);
  }
}
```

here is template:

```
<label class="switcher">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    [checked]="isChecked"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
   />
  <span class="switcher__slider"></span>
</label>
```

and here I started testing:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FlowAssetSwitcherComponent } from './flow-asset-switcher.component';

fdescribe('FlowAssetSwitcherComponent', () => {
let component: FlowAssetSwitcherComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<FlowAssetSwitcherComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [FormsModule],
        declarations: [FlowAssetSwitcherComponent],
    })
        .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FlowAssetSwitcherComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component)
        .toBeTruthy();
});

it('should call onChange when switcher clicked', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'onChange');

    const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.switcher__slider');
    button.click();

    fixture.whenStable()
        .then(() => {
            expect(component.onChange)
                .toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
}));

it('should change isChecked prop when switcher clicked', async(() => {
    const inputEl = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    component.isChecked = true;

    inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    fixture.whenStable()
        .then(() => {
            expect(component.isChecked)
                .toEqual(false);
        });
}));
});
```

So I am testing 3 things:
1. If component is created - test works well
2. Switcher click - test works well
3. Making sure that switcher click actually will change prop which is later emitted - test works only if isChecked is initialized with true value, if its false and should be changed to true test fails and don't know reason

So my basic question is:
How can I check in test if prop value has been change after certain action (click in that case).

and additional question:
Whats the correct way of testing such components as I haven't written any tests before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you could do this, but I like to keep it simple so I would suggest the following:

- When you set the value of `isChecked` you need to then call `fixture.detectChanges()` so that this value is propagated to the input element.
- Just firing off a change event when nothing has actually changed won't be effective.  I suggest simply clicking on the input element which will invoke the change you are looking for.
- Nothing is asynchronous here so `async()` is not strictly needed.

To show these changes in action I put together the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54011532?file=app%2Fflow-asset-switcher.component.spec.ts). Here is a suggested spec with the above changes:

```
it('should change isChecked from false to true when switcher clicked', () => {
    const inputEl = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    component.isChecked = false;
    fixture.detectChanges(); // invoke detectChanges right after you set 'isChecked'

    // inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // <-- This is not needed
    inputEl.click(); // Just invoke 'click' on the inputElement to simulate a mouse click event
    expect(component.isChecked)
        .toEqual(true);
});
```

By the way - thank you for including all the needed details in your question!  That made it easy to create a Stackblitz for testing.

I hope this helps.